# CSS width transition out not working

Tags: html, css

Below is the HTML and CSS I'm using. Unfortunately the questions already asked do not give the answer required. Basically it decreases the width of all siblings and increases the one that is hovered over. I'm using `ease-in-out` but the OUT part of the transition just instantaneously jumps back to its original state.

```css
html {
  background: #000066;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #cfcfd0;
  margin: 4% 4% 4% 4%;
}
#title {
  background: ;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 2%;
  padding: 2% 2%;
}
#nav {
  width: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px
}
ul {
  margin: 4% auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 2% 0;
  margin: 0%;
  background: blue;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul:hover > li:hover {
  width: 37.33%;
  color: white;
  background: darkblue;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
ul:hover > li {
  width: 31.33%;
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <h1>Projects Home</h1>
</div>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Project 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Project 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Project 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I can't figure out why this is.

Comment: Don't put the `transition` properties within the `:hover` selectors. That would mean that the transition applies only when the mouse is over the element and not when otherwise. The transition property should be specified within the `li` selector.

Comment: @Harry that has solved it please post as an answer

Comment: sebastianbrosch's answer is correct except for the *replace* part and so I am not going to post what would be almost a dupe of that. I am happy that the comment helped you :)

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer because the other answer has gone from being a partially correct one (with a wrong statement) to a wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any CSS property gets applied to an element only when the selector is matched. When `transition` property is specified under the `:hover` selector, they naturally get applied only when the hover is on. When we hover out, they just snap back because the `transition` setting is no longer applicable for the element.

In your case, since `transition` is specified only within `ul:hover > li:hover` and `ul:hover >  li`  it gets applied only when the mouse is over an `li` or when the mouse is atleast over the `ul` (that is when we are moving from one `li` to another while still being inside the `ul` boundaries).

To get the `transition` to work properly even during mouse out, it should be specified within the `li` selector like in the below snippet.

```css
html {
  background: #000066;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #cfcfd0;
  margin: 4% 4% 4% 4%;
}
#title {
  background: ;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 2%;
  padding: 2% 2%;
}
#nav {
  width: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px
}
ul {
  margin: 4% auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 2% 0;
  margin: 0%;
  background: blue;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul:hover > li:hover {
  width: 37.33%;
  color: white;
  background: darkblue;
}
ul:hover > li {
  width: 31.33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <h1>Projects Home</h1>
</div>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Project 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Project 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Project 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `>` on `ul:hover > li` to `ul:hover li`:

```css
html {
  background: #000066;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #cfcfd0;
  margin: 4% 4% 4% 4%;
}
#title {
  background: ;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 2%;
  padding: 2% 2%;
}
#nav {
  width: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px
}
ul {
  margin: 4% auto;
  padding:0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 2% 0;
  margin: 0%;
  background: blue;
  border-top:  1px solid black;
  border-bottom:  1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}   
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul:hover > li:hover{
  width: 37.33%;
  color: white;
  background: darkblue;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
ul:hover li {
  width: 31.33%;
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id= "title">
  <h1>Projects Home</h1>
</div>
<div id= "nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Project 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Project 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Project 3</a></li>
  </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: I think OP has `ul:hover li` selector because they want the other two `li` (other than the one being hovered) to decrease in width and hence you shouldn't be *replacing* that selector.

Comment: Unfortunately although it will resolve the animation that leaves me with space on the right side of the three buttons.